# Unroot hacked Xiaomi Poco C40

Tags: factory-reset, xiaomi, unrooting

My Xiaomi Poco C40 was hacked and rooted by a stranger. How to restore to factory settings?

Comment: Quite a few videos on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AOkEu4XY8Rc

Answer (score 4):

If your phone is indeed rooted, it must have its bootloader unlocked. You can restore its factory state from fastboot if bootloader is unlocked.

## WARNING: you will lose all data

- write down your MI account and google account credentials
- [download](https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/archive/miui/frost) the Fastboot Type of MIUI according to your region
- power off the phone
- press Volume Down + Power to enter fastboot mode
- connect the phone to PC
- install [usb drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb)
- install [platform-tools](https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools)
- execute `flash_all.bat`
- reboot when done
- enter your Mi Account password to unlock (FRP)